# How to translate the default validation message

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I'm doing this:

```
//src/Locale/pt_BR/validation.po
msgid "This field cannot be left empty"
msgstr "Este campo não pode ficar em branco"

//config/bootstrap.php
ini_set('intl.default_locale', 'pt_BR');
```

But is not working, I have to do something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `validation` domain, translatable core messages are bound to the `cake` domain. You can use the `I18N` shell to extract all of them.

**http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/i18n-shell.html**